# When I load my data and I print the path of my data I have the back slash in the path

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
print(get_audio_path(AUDIO_DIR, 36096))
```

output

```
C:/Users/adil/Desktop/codes/PROJ 1/fma_small\036\036096.mp3
```

Audio_DIR is my dataset. The problem is in this `\036\036096.mp3`, I want have slash in place of the back slash

Comment: Use raw strings or take a look at pathlib package;

Comment: @Aditya please if you can explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem

```
print(get_audio_path(AUDIO_DIR, 36096).replace('\\', '/'))
```

Then I got in output:

```
C:/Users/adil/Desktop/codes/PROJ 1/fma_small/036/036096.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
print(get_audio_path(AUDIO_DIR, 36096))
```

Try to:

```
test = str(get_audio_path(AUDIO_DIR, 36096))
form = test.replace("\", "/")
print (test)
```

Comment: I have this error  File "<ipython-input-67-5cac34a259e2>", line 1
    test = get_audio_path(AUDIO_DIR, 36096).replace("\", "/")
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: @Adilchakhtouna I have already edited, try with that

Answer (score 0):

```
# your path C:/Users/adil/Desktop/codes/PROJ 1/fma_small\036\036096.mp3
```

It's recommended to use from python 3.4+ [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators) module

```
from pathlib import Path
file = Path.cwd() / "your_fav_dir" / "your_fav_sub_folder" / "your_fav_filename"
```

[This](https://stackabuse.com/introduction-to-the-python-pathlib-module/) is a great resource for skimming the module!

Or If you have problems with some names you can also try raw string literals:

```
r'C:\your_dir\sub_dir' # note it cannot end with a slash
```

Comment: For clarification I use this function :
def get_audio_path(audio_dir, track_id):
    tid_str = '{:06d}'.format(track_id)
    return os.path.join(audio_dir, tid_str[:3], tid_str + '.mp3')

Comment: @Adilchakhtouna Then that's why a zero is there as you want to have 6 digits.. Try this, `'{:06d}'.format(1290)`, you will get `001290`..

Comment: Really I couldn't solve the problem cause I'm beginner :((